# How to do material design effects in GIMP

Tags: gimp, drop-shadow, google-material-design

I have been trying like crazy to get the material design shadowing right. Below is the image I created using GIMP. I have the drop shadow, but I think it kind-of needs to go all around the circles and darker at the bottom, right?

[image]

Comment: "Need" depends on the light source. But your blue bit with the straight edge is throwing shadow up the page, but the circles don't. Also, looking at the shadows, the red circle is on top of everybody, which would mean farthest from the background, which usually would mean that the red circle throws a larger, fainter shadow.

Comment: I may be a layman, but what does this have to do with material design?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - I think he's talking about Google's new design approach which is called "Material Design" - see http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have the drop shadow, but I think it kind-of needs to go all around the circles and darker at the bottom, right?

The answer to this question is available in Google's "Material Design" style guide. The shadow is described [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/environment.html#environment-light-shadow).
In short, you have to have two shadows for each element (each layer in GIMP), for ambient and for directional light, therefore to mimic the requested effect I'd create two shadows for each element.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use three shadows for circle in first shadow 
               offset x = 4 and offset y = 4
Second offset x = 0 and offset y = - 4
And the last one is
              offset x = - 4 and offset y = 0 done.